# QNetworkAccessmanager vs cURL for ftp upload

Tags: c++, qt, upload, ftp, libcurl

I have written a simple ftp uploader in C++ with qt using QNetworkAccessManager's put request

its is working as it should but im not happy with the upload speed i get.

i utilize 80% of my upload line while with filezilla i get 100%

The problem is (at least thats what i think) that Qt using only one connection to upload the 
data while Filezilla uses multiple connections.

I am considering switching to cURL for the ftp uploads.

Finally my question is: Is curl fast?? does it support multiple ftp upload connectionsfor o single file upload??

To clarify i want to know if while uploading ONE file cURL uses multiple connections to the ftp server to achieve better speads.

if not any suggestions for a library that does that would be wellcome
thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cURL allows multi sessions whereby it can perform multiple transfers concurrently.

Cannot really comment though on whether it is fast. The network interaction is likely to be your bottleneck whichever you use.

Comment: i am not interserted in using multiple-session but 1 session with multiple connections but thx for the reply man :)

Comment: That is what a multi-session is. A single session that allows multiple concurrent transfers.